# jpg dont load in CSS/style

Tags: html, css

I have one html page named HOME.HTML  with this code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Home</title>
 </head>
 <style>
       *{
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 0px; }
        body { width: 100vw;
           height: 100vh; 
        background: url('telahome2.jpg') no-repeat top center ; 
        }
 </style>

 <body>

 </body>
 </html>
```

the image file telahome2.jpg is in the root directory but its not loading.
Thanks by any help.

Comment: Are there any errors displayed in your browser console? Check your filename for typos.

Comment: Is `home.html` also in the root directory? If not, it won't be able to find the image.

Answer (score 0):

if your image is in the same folder just write it like this background-image: url(/telahome2.jpg); and don't write "no-repeat top center" these on the same line. you have to write them line this

```
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(/telahome2.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```